# Enable SMB encryption for incoming SMB traffic using REST API

Tags: netapp, ontap

I am trying to enable SMB encryption in ONTAP using the [REST API](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMLP2882307/html/index.html#/). I know how to do it using the CLI but can't find the rest endpoint to do the same. This is CLI command to do what I am trying to in REST API:

```
vserver cifs security modify -vserver vserver_name -is-smb-encryption-required true
```

[Link](https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/smb-admin/enable-disable-encryption-incoming-traffic-task.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I believe I found it. The endpoint that I was after is:

```
/protocols/cifs/services/{svm.uuid}
```

These two resources should be able to help

[POST](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMLP2882307/html/index.html#/NAS/cifs_service_create)

[PATCH](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMLP2882307/html/index.html#/NAS/cifs_service_modify)